# Accessing Picturebox From Stream

Tags: c#, ocr

How can I access picturebox1 from my ocr.Image = img bit of the code. I have it working if I load it by using

ocr.Image = ImageStream.FromFile("C:/Users/John/Pictures/3.jpg");   // Give the image to the library

but obviously thats not what I am tryng to achive.

Error is:

> cannot implicitly convert type system.drawing.image to
>   apose.ocr.iimagestream

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            //SendKeys.Send("{PRTSC}");
            Image img = Clipboard.GetImage();
            pictureBox1.Image = img;


            //ocr processing

            ocr.Image = img;  // Give the image to the library
            if (ocr.Process()) // Start processing it
            {
                label1.Text = "Text: " + ocr.Text;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(img!=null)
{
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg); // put here the image format
    ms.Position = 0;

    ocr.Image = ImageStream.FromStream(ms,ImageStreamFormat.Jpg);
    ..
    ..//all your processing stuff
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newbie - is this saving an image somewhere? would this resource hog because its within a timer. Also, its getting red underline on ImageFormat.Jpg - does this need to be in quotes?

Comment: it's ImageFormat.Jpeg . It's not in quotes because it's an enum. No it's not saving the image but of course performance can be an issue if the image size is big.

Comment: Ahh thats fine, that's what I hoped it' do - I'm sorry this is a newbie question but the ImageFormat.Jpeg highlights red

Comment: did you put using System.Drawing; at the beginning of the file ? Try to compile.

Comment: Yup its there, but says ImageFormat does not exist in current context

Comment: Add these too: using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO; are you using visual studio ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159917/discussion-between-bcltd-and-farbiondriven).